# Django: "Cannot assign must be a "X" instance", don't want to fetch the object

Tags: django

I have the following view on my Django app and I need to update one object

`status_id` is a `ForeignKey` field and it has some default values loaded via fixtures

```
def stopObject(request, id_object):
    object = Object.objects.get(id=id_object)
    object.status_id = 1
    object.save()
```

I'm getting the classical error where I need to assign the object, not its Id. There are countless questions on SO about this problem, but I came looking for an answer I didn't found

I know very well I can just perform a fetch from the database and assign to `status`, but I want to explore other possibilities, even though they may not be the best practices

EDIT sharing the models:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

class Object(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    status_id = models.ForeignKey(Status,
                                  db_column="status_id",
                                  default=3,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True,
                                  related_name='objects',
                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # other fields
```

Comment: Share the related model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `status_id` is a `ForeignKey`.

Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should be `status`, instead of <s>`status_id`</s>, so:

```
class Object(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        Status,
        default=3,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='objects',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
```

this then also prevents having to specify the `db_column='status_id'`.

If you thus rename the field to `status`, you can use `status_id`. If not, you can use:

```
# if the field is named status
def stopObject(request, id_object):
    object = Object.objects.get(id=id_object)
    object.status_id = 1
    object.save()
```

If you decide to keep it `status_id` for some reason, we can use:

```
# if the field is remains status_id
def stopObject(request, id_object):
    object = Object.objects.get(id=id_object)
    object.status_id_id = 1
    object.save()
```

You can boost performance further by just updating the `Object` instead of fetching and saving:

```
# if the field is remains status_id
def stopObject(request, id_object):
    object = Object.objects.filter(id=id_object).update(status_id_id=1)
```

or with the renamed field:

```
# if the field is named status
def stopObject(request, id_object):
    object = Object.objects.filter(id=id_object).update(status_id=1)
```

---

> **Note**: Django will add by default an [**`AutoField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#autofield) as `primary_key=True` to a model with name `id` if you do not specify a primary key yourself, so there is no need to explicitly declare a primary key.

Comment: You're right, it's just the `_id` suffix that kept me from doing this. I know Django also appended a suffix automatically, just though the framework could ignore if I did this manually. I renamed `status_id` to `status` and kept the `db_column` field just for the sake of keeping explicit the name. I'm going to take this into account now when creating and updating other models